# KDB/q - How to display static HTML on the HTTP port?

Tags: kdb

How to display a static HTML page on the HTTP port of a q session rather than showing the list of available variables and functions?

Comment: Apache or Ngnix? Github Pages?

Comment: A KDB/q session running on a port serves the http requests too. [wiki](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/#117-http-and-web-sockets) . I want to change the default output when the port is accessed using http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the `.z.ph` function to return the static HTML content.

```
q)con:"<html><body><h1 style=\"font-family:verdana;\">Static</h1><p style=\"font-family:courier;\">Static HTML page.</p></body></html>";

q).z.ph:{[x;y] "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Length: ",(string count x),"\n\n" ,x} [con;]
```